# Choosing model to send out of multiple options from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 models ModelA and ModelB having exactly same fields but both are 2 different tables in database and let's  say both have 2 string fields for TextA and TextB. . 
What i want to do is that, i want to make a single view which will have a dropbox to choose from the 2 models (ModelA and ModelB) and provide 2 textfields for TextA and TextB. 
On clicking submit button of the form i want that according to the value of dropbox choosen at that time, that specific model be sent to controller and controller after identifying the model add the record just passed to the right table in the database. 
Please help me know how can i do it using asp.net mvc

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what you can do is create a 3rd model that is used only in the view since modelA and modelB are the same and then map this model to ModelA or ModelB depending on the selection

Comment: That would work for me... Thank you so much villa_pr

Comment: Glad I can help, please remember to mark the answer so if anyone else have the same problem know what answer help you